# How to view width of element while animating?

Tags: jquery, html, width, jquery-animate

I animate simply object using:

```
$("#progress").animate({width:400},2000)
```

Than i also want to view it's width like that

```
$("#loadingpro").html(pro+"%");

pro = Math.round(procent$("#progress").width()/4);
```

But when I am doing it like that it's start to delay whole cpu so much that it is not possible to do it at all.

Any ideas how I can try to do it in other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** and **[`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)**. Play around with the interval to get it smooth. ~20 microseconds is what worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $("#loadingpro").html(Math.round($("#progress").width()/4) + "%");
    },20);
    $("#progress").animate({width:400},2000, function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpng2/)**

`.setInterval()` is a good choice, since you can stop it with `clearInterval()` in the **[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** callback once all your calculations are done.

Comment: @Drink86 - You're welcome ;) Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem (check mark next to the vote count).